# Как задать рикошет по недоставленным письмам на виртуальном выделенном сервере?

Tags: apache

Есть виртуальный выделеный сервер, на нем php, на нем - сайт. Зачастую люди жалуются, что письма, которые автоматически отправляются с сайта, не доходят (при регистрации, например). А мне при этом не приходят рикошет (когда письмо не доставлено просто через почту - приходит в обратку сообщение об ошибке, а через сайт - нет). Где настроить то, на какой адрес должен приходить этот рикошет (письмо о том, что исходное сообщение не доставлено)? Где это включается/выключается вообще как функция?

Вообще, я-то ожидала, что вернется письмо с ошибкой на тот адрес, который стоит в параметре "от", но нет.

Помогите, плз

Answer (score 1):

> Вообще, я-то ожидала, что вернется письмо с ошибкой на тот адрес, который стоит в параметре "от", но нет.

Зря ожидала.

> Every e-mail message has a hidden field called the "**Return-Path**" address (sometimes called a "bounce address" or "envelope sender address"). This should be the address a message really came from, and it's the address to which any undeliverable message notices ("bounces") are sent.

Comment: Ответ ни о чем. Знаете, как решить вопрос - напишите и по-русски

Comment: Вам перевести?

Comment: @tsuki, вам вместо рыбы дали удочку - рыбу наловите сами. В чем проблема?В двух словах... Изыщите способ подкидывать в скрытое поле Return-Path (bounce address, envelope sender address) адрес отправителя.ЗЫ Вы же не надеетесь, что мы в знаем Ваше окружение с точностью до версии используемого ПО?

Comment: Я не понимаю, почему нельзя сказать по-человечески? Почему нельзя ответить "нужно в заголовках письма поставить параметр Return-Path с адресом, куда должны возвращаться ошибки" (если я правильно понимаю, что вы имеете в виду). Почему нужно вставлять какие-то куски на английском, сайт русский и писать нужно по-русски или вставлять английский текст, но обязательно с переводом. Не знаю я английского достаточно, чтобы это прочитать и понять, что Вы пишите. И не должна знать.

Comment: @pyatak, зря Вы так...)@tsuki, Вам всего лишь привели выдержку из документации. В IT-сообществе это нормально. Нормально также давать ссылку на документ и посылать курить маны.ЗЫ Кстати, @tsuki. Если перевести на человеческий, то эта выдержка из документации примерно означает как раз "нужно в заголовках письма поставить параметр Return-Path с адресом, куда должны возвращаться ошибки". Наслаждайтесь ;) Просто у Вас может не оказаться параметра Return-Path, но зато будет, например, "envelope sender address". А переводы не всегда отражают суть... Вот незнание английского - зло. Избавляйтесь!